# angular/material2 .md-sidenav-content width 100%

Tags: angular, angular-material2

Is it possible to have the sidenav content take the full width in angular/material2 ?
If you follow the tuto on the website, you can define your content like this:

```
<md-sidenav-container>
  <md-sidenav>
    <!-- sidenav content -->
  </md-sidenav>

  <!-- primary content -->
</md-sidenav-container>
```

But what they really do is they add an `<div class="md-sidenav-content" ...>`
 element that wraps your "primary content".

Is it possible to give that element a `width:100%`? Or even better, a `flex: 1 1 100%;` styling?
Just adding that in the css for the `.md-sidenav-content` class doesn't seem to work...

Comment: It is possible. Just need to add width: 100% on md-sidenav element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nevermind. I found the solution. 
I had a `display: flex;` on the `<md-sidenav-container>` element. Removing that did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. You just need to add width: 100% on md-sidenav element.

```
<md-sidenav #sideNav style="width: 100%"></md-sidenav>
```

Comment: sorry if I wasn't clear enough, but want I wanted was to have the "primary content" not the "sidenav content" to have a width 100%.
But I found the solution. I had a display: flex; on the md-sidenav-container. Removing that did the trick. 
thx.